# Error while decompress a file from Local Linux to HDFS

Tags: linux, hdfs

This command works  fine in Local linux

```
gzip -d omega_data_path_2016-08-10.csv.gz
```

I would like to decompress a file with extension .csv.gz to HDFS location.

I tried the below command and i get this error

```
 [cloudera@client08 localinputfiles]$ gzip -d omega_data_path_2016-08-10.csv.gz | hadoop dfs -put /user/cloudera/inputfiles/
gzip: omega_data_path_2016-08-10.csv already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)? DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

put: `/user/cloudera/inputfiles/': No such file or directory
```

Could someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make `gzip` write the output on standard output, use `-c` flag.

So the command would be,

```
gzip -dc omega_data_path_2016-08-10.csv.gz | hdfs dfs -put - /user/cloudera/omega_data_path_2016-08-10.csv
```

Comment: What is the use of -dc ? can I use gzip -c  instead of gzip -dc?

Comment: `-d` is for decompress.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped

Comment: Just curious, why would you decompress and store it in HDFS?

Comment: That decompressed file will be consumed by hadoop and spark applications and some hive tables will be pointing them.

Comment: Hadoop can consume Gzip files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141567/discussion-between-surender-raja-and-franklinsijo).